# Center paragraph with background

Tags: css, background, center, paragraph

I would like to know how to center (width) a paragraph with a background.

Something like this[image]

Thanks a lot :)

```
<div class="about_content">
<h1>Devenez le maitre de vos réseaux !</h1>
<p>Bienvenue dans la nouvelle bulle d’échange d’informations “Spotlinks” <br>Echangez et connectez sur le moment  vos données sociales et professionnelles</p>
</div>

.about_content {
padding: 200px;
h1{
font-size: 53px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #333;
}
p {
text-align: center;
background: white;
color: $text-color;
display: inline-block;
}
}
```

Comment: `text-align: center;`? Question must show a minimum level of effort on your part with what you have tried. What have you tried..?

Comment: okay...first...its a very basic question to ask, shud have googled first.....second...i wonder why you dint googled it and third...if it's tough...where is code for our reference mate? ;)

Comment: I'll never understand why people don't search before they post... :/

Comment: I searched... The probleme is that I can get that result. I only have a full white background ! Tried texte-align: center;

But it does not work. I get a full width background!

Comment: so provide us your code....how can you expect solution from us when we don't know the problem....makes sense????!!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So then the problem is because `<p>` is a block-level element, and if you give it a background colour it will span the full width.

A workaround would be to add a `<span>` tag inside the `<p>` tag and set the background colour on the `<span>`, because it is by default an inline element. You will also need to set the `<span` CSS to `display:inline-block`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3LLt/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <p><span>My text here</span></p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container { background:#ccc; padding:10px;}
p { text-align:center; }
p span { display:inline-block; background:#fff; padding:5px;}
```

Comment: This work. But I needed to let the span as a inline element!

Thanks a lot!